# Getting a tag from XML document in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create a weather app and for that to work i need to be able to get a specefic tag from an XML file. I have managed to get a specific child node, but i cant seem to get a tag.

My main target is to get the tag "value="4" in temperature.

My XML and XSL file is shown below:

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>
<title>Sjekk været</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Været og valutaen i Kanada:</h1>



<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Vær</th>
    <th>Norske kroner</th>
    <th>Kanadiske dollar</th>
  </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="valuta/valutakurs[land='Canada']/overforsel">
    <xsl:for-each select="document('http://www.yr.no/sted/Canada/Ontario/Toronto/varsel.xml')/weatherdata/forecast/tabular/time">
  <tr>
    -------> I want to show the tag in this field<-------
    <td><xsl:value-of select="temperature"/></td>
    <td>1 NOK</td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="kjop"/> CAD</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

</table>


</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<weatherdata>
<location>...</location> 
<credit>...</credit> <links>...</links> 
<meta>...</meta> 
<sun rise="2018-10-24T07:43:16" set="2018-10-24T18:19:47"/> 
<forecast> 
<tabular> 
<time from="2018-10-24T07:00:00" to="2018-10-24T12:00:00" period="1"> 
<!-- Valid from 2018-10-24T07:00:00 to 2018-10-24T12:00:00 --> 
<symbol number="3" numberEx="3" name="Delvis skyet" var="03d"/> 
<precipitation value="0"/> 
<!-- Valid at 2018-10-24T07:00:00 --> 
<windDirection deg="317.9" code="NW" name="Nordvest"/> 
<windSpeed mps="3.7" name="Lett bris"/> 
<temperature unit="celsius" value="4"/> 
<pressure unit="hPa" value="1024.5"/> </time>
```

Comment: Have you got a main XML you are working with? The XSLT first tries to select `valuta/valutakurs` which is not in the XML snippet you have shown (I think your snippet is what is returned by the external document `http://www.yr.no....`). Thanks

Comment: Yes, here is my main XML https://www.dnb.no/portalfront/datafiles/miscellaneous/csv/kursliste_ws.xml

Comment: It helps to get the terminology right (without that, how can you do a google search?) In your code, `<forecast>`, `<pressure unit="hPa" value="1024.5"/>`, and `</time>` are examples of tags, while `value="4"` is an attribute. In the XSLT processing model, you don't look for tags, you look for element and attribute nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, to get the value of the temperature in the external document, do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="temperature/@value"/>
```

This is because `value` is an "attribute" of the `temperature` element, so you use the `@` prefix to denote attributes.

However, you will also have a problem with getting your `kjop` element, because at the point you try to get it, you are in the context of your external document, whereas `kjop` is an element on your original document. So, what you need to do is save a reference to the element in your original document, so you can refer back to it when you start selecting from the external document.

Try this snippet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="valuta/valutakurs[land='Canada']/overforsel">
  <xsl:variable name="overforsel" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="document('http://www.yr.no/sted/Canada/Ontario/Toronto/varsel.xml')/weatherdata/forecast/tabular/time">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="temperature/@value"/></td>
      <td>1 NOK</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$overforsel/kjop"/> CAD</td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```